# Hibernate turn off cache - Can't see changes made directly on database in app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have simple problem. When I edit something directly in database for example by UPDATE statement I can't see any changes in my application. I read somewhere that this is reason of Hibernate cache or am wrong ?

My hibernate configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="transactionPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestTable?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="uberSecretUsername" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="uberSecretPassword" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Its pretty basic nothing here that can surprise you. How can I disable this cache or how can I get this working. I just want simple see changes in app when I make changes directly on database

Comment: Are you closing the entityManager? If you don't, it might be your problem.

Comment: You are only using the first level cache (which you can not turn off). The second level cache may cause it to act this way but you are not using second level caching which must be explicitly turned on.

Comment: I'm using PersistenceContext so why shoud I close entityManager ? @BillFromHawaii you are telling that second level can help or I'am wrong ?

Comment: No - your post indicates that you think this could be caused by Hibernate caching, I'm telling you that Hibernate caching is not the cause.